# How to view the source code in spark job in .jar file

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, decompiling

I have a spark job in .jar format . I wanted to view the source code in that file.
How can I do that, using what IDE I need to check that code.
I have downloaded the .jar file from aws in s3 location. I wanted to check the code in my local machine. What should I download for that or can I check the code in aws itself.

Can anyone please help me with this

Answer (score 1):

Download java-decompiler from http://java-decompiler.github.io/

You will be able to load jar file in the jd-gui app and view the source code.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/), you can simply open the file ([as their blog explains here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/03/java-bytecode-decompiler/)), or you can click into the class file from the project explorer (just double-click as if opening the file). This feature is included in the free version of IntelliJ ("Community").

[image]

Once you accept the warning, the decompiled code shows up in the main text editor pane.